# Using storyboard from "Build" present view from ApplicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that is loaded from a `UIStoryboard` file. This file is selected from the project settings. i.e. I'm not loading it manually from `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

However, I have an additional "intro" view that I want to present on first run.

I'm doing this in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`...

```
NSNumber *seenIntroNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"seenIntro"];

BOOL seenIntro = seenIntroNumber != nil && [seenIntroNumber boolValue];

if (!seenIntro) {
    IntroViewController *controller = [[IntroViewController alloc] init];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:^{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@YES forKey:@"seenIntro"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }];
}
```

However, this isn't working as I think this is running before the actual view controllers are loaded.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I din't get why it isn't working. What exactly is happening? The IntroViewController is never shown? Can u check the rootViewController property of the window to check if it is nil?

Comment: Yeah, the root view controller is nil. The views seem to be loaded after application did finish launching runs. It tells me I'm trying to present from a view controller that isn't in the view hierarchy.